# Swift : Updated Variable in a different scene

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, var, scene

I've got a variable in my GameScene, it's score variable, and it's being displayed on screen with SKLabelNode.

Everytime time there is a collision, 1 is being added to score, which is being transfered as a string to the SKLabelNode, and then updated on screen.

Problem is, when I call it from my GameOverScene (scene where the final score is being displayed along with "game over"), I get first value of score, which is 0. Like GameOverScene is reading variable, but not the updated one.
How to get the updated variable? Can anyone help?

Code:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    // S C O R E !
    var score = 0
    var scoreText: String = ""

    var scoreOnScreen = SKLabelNode()
...

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // S C O R E
    scoreOnScreen.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height * 0.8)
    scoreText = String(score)
    scoreOnScreen.text = scoreText
```

when collision takes place, score get's +1

```
func bulletDidCollideWithEnemy(enemy: SKSpriteNode, bullet: SKSpriteNode) {

        score++
        scoreText = String(score)
        scoreOnScreen.text = scoreText
```

and then, the GameOverScene:

```
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    let GameSceneInstance = GameScene()
    let bgImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")
    let afraidLogo = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "gameoverlogo")
    var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        GameSceneInstance.scoreOnScreen.text = String(GameSceneInstance.score)

        bgImage.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        bgImage.setScale(0.75)
        addChild(bgImage)

        afraidLogo.position = CGPoint(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
        afraidLogo.setScale(0.50)
        addChild(afraidLogo)

        gameOverLabel.fontSize = 40
        gameOverLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        gameOverLabel.text = "score: \(GameSceneInstance.scoreOnScreen.text)"
        gameOverLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, 2.0 / 3.0 * self.size.height);
        addChild(gameOverLabel)

    }
```

I bet it's just a simple issue with the code. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out with some help from a reddit guy with a nickname Jasamer. Guy rocks.

Here's what I've changed:

when the scene is being changed

```
let scene = GameOverScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
```

I added:

```
    scene.gameScene = self
    scene.score = score
```

and then, the GameOverScene:

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

    var gameScene = GameScene()
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
   gameOverLabel.text = "score: \(gameScene.score)"
```

and it works.

The main problem I think was not setting `scene.GameScene = self`.

I hope this helps someone someday.